# saving a file in internal storage and retrieve its path

Tags: java, android, file

I have this piece of code for saving accelerometer data in a file , but i cant find that file in my internal storage.

```
String file_name="hello_file";
try {
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream=openFileOutput(file_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fileOutputStream.write(message.getBytes());
    fileOutputStream.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    acceleration.setText("");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getFilesDir()` gives the location of where `openFileOutput()` writes files.

That said, those files are not accessible by users. They could access them actually but if they had a rooted device at hand.

Here's a tutorial regarding `Internal and External` storage.

I don't know how much you know about Android storage but just to clarify `External` isn't really external in the sense of an external hard-drive. It's external as on a different `partition` from the one holding the `OS`. It is still 'internal' in the sense that it's not on an `sdcard`. But still even if you don't have an SD card installed, Android could name your external(non-system) storage sdcard/ .... So yeah, lots of confusion initially.